# Consolidating rows in Excel based on certain criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have been breaking my head on this for the entire day. Essentially we have a 500,000+ record excel sheet that has information/rows that need to be consolidated into one row to be able to import it into our accounting software.

```
TRNS    48150   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         23.62    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A        286.26    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A        -23.62       
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A       -286.26
```

All the records that have the Account number 20-000-01000-A have to be sum'd up in one line per TRNSID. What i need it to look like is:

```
TRNS    48150   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         23.62
SPL     48150   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A        286.26
SPL     48150   BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A       -309.88
```

Of course i did try my best but with no results. I'm not much of a VBA programmer, so I imported it into Access to try and run queries to get it to work, But it didn't. I also tried this, but keep getting an error. I would appreciate the help.

```
Sub fun()

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    If Range("E:E").Value = "20-000-01000-A" Then
    Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=5, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(8)
```

### End Sub

```
TRNS    48150   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         23.62    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A        286.26    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A        -23.62       
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A       -286.26
ENDTRNS
TRNS    48151   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A          1.87 
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         14.65
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A          8.06
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A        - 1.87    
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A        -14.65       
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A         -8.06
ENDTRNS
```

---

This is the results I need. Where only the rows with 20-000-01000-A are consolidated into one line.

```
TRNS    48150   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         23.62    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A        286.26    
SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A       -309.88       
ENDTRNS
TRNS    48151   BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A          1.87 
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A         14.65
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A          8.06    
SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A        -24.58       
ENDTRNS
```

Comment: Why does "SPL    48151    BILL    1/13/2012   11-000-150300-A" duplicated but "SPL    48150    BILL    1/13/2012   20-000-010000-A" isn't.

Comment: Its the format the software needs it in. all credits have to be per line and all debits have to be consolidated into one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something without using macro.

First you copy the first 5 columns to another Sheet and then use RemoveDuplicates (Data Menu).
Then you can do  `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!F:F, Sheet1!A:A, RC1, Sheet2!B:B, RC2, Sheet2!C:C, RC3, Sheet2!D:D, RC4, Sheet2!E:E, RC5)`

I'm Expecting Columns like this:

```
 A     B    C      D              E        F
TRNS 48150 BILL 1/13/2012 11-000-150300-A 23.62
```

**Edit:**

You can use Pivot Table too.

** Edit2:**
Sorry man, i don't have much time to do a beautiful code for you with all verifications. I'm deleting rows, using flags and so on (all the worst things that you can do in the code), but it fits the purpose. :-)

```
Sub MakahHelper()
    Dim lastRow As Integer, matches() As Double, i As Double, total As Double

    lastRow = Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    matches = MatchAll("ENDTRNS", Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)))

    For i = UBound(matches) To 1 Step -1
        'Get the blocks that ends in ENDTRNS.
        firstRow = IIf(i = 1, 1, matches(i - 1) + 1)
        lastRow = matches(i) - 1
        Set theRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, 1), Cells(lastRow, 6))

        'Order
        With ActiveSheet
            .Sort.SortFields.Clear
            .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=theRange.Columns(5), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .Sort
                .SetRange theRange
                .Header = xlNo
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        End With

        total = 0
        firstOccurrence = False
        'Find the lastRowCons ocurrence of "20-000-010000-A"
        For j = lastRow To firstRow Step -1
            If Cells(j, 5) = "20-000-010000-A" Then
                total = total + Cells(j, 6)

                'Use the first row to consolidate the values (workarround, i'm lazy)
                If Not firstOccurrence Then
                    firstOccurrence = True
                Else
                    Rows(j).Delete
                    lastRow = lastRow - 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

        'Add the value to the first Entry of "20-000-010000-A"
        If firstOccurrence Then
            rowIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match("20-000-010000-A", Range(Cells(firstRow, 5), Cells(lastRow, 5)), 0)
            Cells(firstRow + rowIndex - 1, 6) = total
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Public Function MatchAll(ByVal value As String, ByVal theRange As Range) As Double()
    Dim index As Long, rFoundCell As Range, total As Integer, results() As Double

    total = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(theRange, value)
    If total = 0 Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    ReDim results(total)

    Set rFoundCell = theRange.Cells(1, 1)
    For index = 1 To total

        Set rFoundCell = theRange.Find(What:=value, After:=rFoundCell, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

        results(index) = rFoundCell.Row
    Next index

    MatchAll = results
End Function
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the very first thing i noticed is that it deleted rows that had 11-000-150300-A. I just need it to combine rows that have 20-000-01000-A for each TRNSID.

Comment: `@Makah` I have been trying my best to put a more accurate table up for you to see, but i really can't figure out how to code it in properly. It looks good at first, but when i hit "add Comment" it just jumbles the columns and rows all together.

Comment: I didn't see your comment before. You can edit your question to put more example.

Comment: Do you know how SUMIF and SUMIFS works? I think you can use just it.

Comment: `@Makah` I have updated my original post to more clearly demonstrate what I need to happen with this spread sheet. I tried with the SumIFs, but it didn't work, at least for me.

Comment: I would agree! but we would have to debug it first xD! The matchall function seems to make the macro start at line 46 and end at line 49. I also get a mismatch error 13 when i try to run the macro. I really appreciate your help in this matter!

Comment: My matchAll finds where "ENDTRNS" is. So i think you have the last "ENDTRNS" in line 46 and the code ends in 49. Am i right? Which line do you have error 13?

Comment: total = total + Cells(j, 6) is where the debug points to. Line 46 is SPL but line 45 is ENDTRNS. line 50 is also ENDTRNS. So from my understanding, its stuck between these 2 ENDTRNS.

Comment: Sorry man, I can't help if you don't understand anything about VBA. :-)... can you enter in my profile, get my email and send me the Excel file? So I can fix it for you.

Comment: Yeah, I know the very very basic of VBA. I do SQL mainly and C++ on rare occasions. Some of the syntax in VBA confuses me.